# Vertical centred fullscreen div with scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment, html5-fullscreen

I would like to make fullscreen, vertical centred `div` overlaying all content below.

```
/* css */
#box {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/* It is <body> tag class */
.overlay-hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}

<!-- html -->
<body class="overlay-hidden">
    <div id="box">
        <!-- #box popup content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/uzy78s69/
It seems work great but when I add more content to `#box` it does not work well https://jsfiddle.net/uzy78s69/1/

Click `X` or `Create new post` to check behaviour.

What I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: have check `align-items: center;` this part... when i unchecked it it works....I think you want like this???

Comment: **vertical centered full-screen**    what you meant?  what is the purpose to center a full width content?

Comment: @dreamhunter By fullscreen I have meant to overflow all browser area `width: 100%; height: 100%`. `div` should be also vertically and horizontally centred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
#box > .container {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

JSfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/uzy78s69/3](https://jsfiddle.net/uzy78s69/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `display:flex;` from `#box` class.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bk0arf02/3/)